# I'm not using StringFormat correctly

Tags: xaml

I'm having problems with StringFormat, there must be a mistake in my syntax, i'm getting format symbols mixed with values in the final result (see screenshot attached). I export to PDF to get to that, but i don't think that's really important, if I remove the XAML Formatting the sum() shows perfectly (but no formatting is done), I think the problem must be in StringFormat line. Thanks.

```
<Custom:SummaryDefinition 
      Calculator="Sum" 
 SourceFieldName="ImporteMonPaisInf" 
    StringFormat="{}{0:0.##;(0.##)}">
```

[image: Case 1]

```
    <Custom:SummaryDefinition 
      Calculator="Sum" 
 SourceFieldName="ImporteMonPaisInf"
    StringFormat="{}{0:C2}
```

[image]

Comment: Which format are you trying to get? Moreover, the string format should go between one pair of curly braces and you have two sets of those in your code

Comment: About the {}{...} brackets they are valid, see this: http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/wpf-stringformat-in-xaml-with-the-stringformat-attribute/ About the formatting: Getting 2 decimals always would be enough for me, the problem right now is not which format, it's why those formatting symbols are getting there, there has to be something wrong with that line.

Comment: Why you do not simply use {}{0:C2}

Comment: See 2nd screenshot attached in first post, that happens when using {}{0:C2}

Comment: Thats really weird. I suggest you check the correctness of your braces and closing tags. Also have a look here: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/the-stringformat-property/

Comment: Am I right in assuming that the missing close quote in the second example is just a typo?

Comment: You don't need the 2 sets of curly braces if you escape the curly braces, like so: StringFormat='\{0:N0\}'

Comment: Solved, the problem wasn't StringFormat, it was that later when exporting I was using the same Format with .NET String.Format() and both things are not the same, i had to alter the formatting string to make it compatible with String.Format() by removing {} and : thanks all.